# What is the difference between policy gradient methods and neural network-based action-value methods?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

What is the difference between policy gradient methods and neural network-based action-value methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to differentiate between "action selection" and "action-value estimation".

Action-value (denoted by `Q(s, a)`) estimation consists in calculating some sort of "score" (often called the "expected future reward") for a particular action `a` in a given state `s`. We just estimate this value `Q(s, a)`, but we still don't know what action we will take.

Then, there is an action selection, which is a function `f` which, based on some information, returns an action we perform.

A broad class named as **action-value methods** are "action selection" methods, which, when given an action-value estimates (scores) `Q`, give us an action to perform. An example of such method is **epsilon-greedy method**. This method with probability `1 - epsilon` picks an action with highest action-value score and with a probability of `epsilon` (which is usually a small number) picks an action at random. The only information we utilize are the Q scores.

**Policy gradient** methods perform **action selection**. The information we give to `f` is the current state `s` and some parameters `theta`: `f(s, theta)` We can imagine these parameters `theta` to be weights of a neural network. So, in practice, we would set the weights of a neural network to the values of `theta`, give the network state `s` as an input and get an action `a` as output. This is just one example of what policy gradient method may look like. We don't need any state-value or action-value estimates to get the policy. Furthermore, the function `f` must be differentiable.

**Actor-Critic** methods also perform **action selection**. The difference from policy gradient methods is that the function `f` also accepts the action-value estimates, i.e. `Q`, as input: `f(s, theta, Q)`. We need action-value estimates to get action.

You can read more about the differences in "*Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction*" by Sutton and Barto in Chapter 13: Policy Gradient Methods.

Comment: Thanks but i don't get it. In DeepMind's paper about playing Atari with deep reinforcement learning, We give just screen images as an input and the network returns 8 actions Q-values, then we choose the biggest one. in this form, We are not giving available actions to network, we just give current state! Im not talking about Q-Value estimation. In a very large and continuous space of problems we can't give action-value pairs to network. Deepmind gives just state and get proper action to take. In Gradient Policy methods we do same thing. but what is the difference between these two.

Comment: Okay, I apologize for long delay. I also got confused. The method they implement in the paper is NOT a policy gradient method. They use the neural network as a parametric approximation of the action values (i.e. action-values estimator) and then they perform action selection purely on these action values approximations (epsilon-greedy). 
The neural network is parametrized by some `w`, receives a state `s` (which in their case is history of 4 frames) and **produces action value estimates** q(s,a,w) for all actions `a` for one particular state `s`.